# JS - baseURLString when sending pathnames only

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to create a `new URL` in JS so it can be manipulated for an async request. As nothing is cross-origin (I think this is the correct usage of that term), the URLs I send for async request look like `/MyLoginUrl` or /`MyUpdateDataUrl`, etc. (i.e. I am only sending the pathname).

My attempt to create a `new URL` from an existing url looked basically like this:

```
// Actually I set the url as an arguement in a function,
// but for demonstration it will be a variable
var url = '/myPathname';

// Much later...
url = new URL (url);
```

However, this was returning a syntax error. Once I looked a [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL), I found out why.

Per the docs, the syntax for a `new URL` looks like this:

> `url = new URL(urlString, [baseURLstring])`
>
> `url = new URL(urlString, baseURLobject)`

The docs also say:

> `baseURLstring`: is a DOMString representing the base URL to use in case urlString is a relative URL. If not specified, and no baseURLobject is passed in parameters, it default to 'about:blank'. If it is an invalid absolute URL, the constructor will raise a DOMException of type SYNTAX_ERROR

A couple of examples in the docs for a `baseURLstring` is:

```
var a = new URL("/", "https://developer.mozilla.org"); // Creates a URL pointing to 'https://developer.mozilla.org/'
var b = new URL("https://developer.mozilla.org");      // Creates a URL pointing to 'https://developer.mozilla.org/'
var c = new URL('en-US/docs', b);                      // Creates a URL pointing to 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs'
```

**Thus, I am trying to figure out how to emulate a `baseURLstring` for, currently, `localhost` and eventually when this gets hosted by the main server I will use for my network, the `baseURLstring` for that. I'm guessing it would involve in some way getting the IP address of the computer I have/of the server on the network, or maybe not...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can test this

```
var base_url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/';
```

Comment: It is usually helpful to add a bit of commentary as to what your code is doing and how it solves the problem. Probably a one-liner bit of text would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

`baseURLstring` will the url of your website, lets take the example of Google:
base url of google is `https://www.google.com` similarly your baseurlstring will be something like this `https://www.yourwebsiteaddress.com` and the first parameter in `url = new URL(urlString, [baseURLstring])` is the path of the files placed on your server (root folder, where your default index file is placed)

Comment: tku, I understand that. I am trying to get the `baseURLstring` of `localhost`, or whatever "on-a-network" baseURL is being used